# json string becomes null in action class in struts 1.3.8

Tags: java, ajax

i am developing a web application in struts 1.3.8 i am using $.ajax() jquery to  post json data into my action class but i am receiving null .my code

```
var dataobj={data:[{code:code1,hd1:h1,hd2:h2}]};
 $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "EditablePage.do?data="+dataobj,
                    dataType: "json",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:dataobj

                });
```

java code

```
    String data=request.getParameter("data");
    JSONObject jObj    = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject newObj=jObj.getJSONObject(data);
```

**String data=request.getParameter("data");**
this is becoming null not understanding where i am doing wrong iam new in Jquery, any hint would be a great help for me

Answer (score 0):

Your way of creating JSONObject is wrong. Change your code to this:

```
String data = request.getParameter("data");
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
```

Also, sending a JSON data as a parameter string isn't advisable. Rather send it as an entity body in Javascript.